# Multiple raycast with restrictions

Tags: c#, vector, unity-game-engine, detection, raycasting

I have this problem which I have been trying to figure out for quite some time already. The code I have below is almost complete. I just need to add this additional feature it should work how I want it to work.

So what I want to implement into the code is the make alertedLock false when !withinRange.
But for some reason no matter how i do it. It doesnt work. Because the problem i have is that, when i implement some kind of code to do that, everything goes back to normal.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
The script should be doing this:

1. If player !withinRange && !withinAngle of enemy then, enemy.color.blue;

If player is not within Range for enemy to detect and player is not within certain Angle for enemy to detect. It means, player is not detected by enemy. So we use Color.Blue to represent that.

2. If player !withinRange &&  withinAngle of enemy then, enemy.color.blue;

If player is not within Range for enemy to detect and player is within Angle for enemy to detect. It means, player is still not detect by enemy. So we use Color.Blue to represent that.

3. If player  withinRange && !withinAngle of enemy then, enemy.color.red;
   If player is within Range for enemy to detect and player is not within Angle for enemy to detect player. It means, enemy has detected something within Range but doesnt meet all the requirements, that is, withinAngle = true. So in this case we use Color.Red to represent that.
4. If player  withinRange && withinAngle of enemy then, enemy.color.green;

If player is within Range for enemy to detect and player is within Angle for enemy to detect player. It means, player has successfully killed the the enemy. Therefore, using Color.Green to represent that.

5. If player  withinRange && touchRestrictedRaycast of enemy then, enemy.color.magenta (forever) unless !withinRange && !withinAnge

If player is within Range for enemy to detect and player is not within Angle for enemy to detect player. But however then hits the raycast, touchRestrictedRaycast. This will make a lock. So the player cant kill the enemy from a invalid position. So when this happens, the player can no longer kill the enemy. Unless the player is totally out of Range of the enemies detection.

The problem is 5. I dont know how to code 5.
**Edit**
When i tried to code it outside the forloop , that is,

```
if (alertedLock && !withinRange) {

    alertedLock = false;        

}
```

Does doesnt solve the problem. It returns the solution to where alertedLock is always false
Even when i try to apply it inside the for loop. Such like,

```
if(withinRange) {
        // Inside
        if(alertedLock) {
            gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.magenta;
        }
        if(!alertedLock) {
            if(enemyAngleTLUP || enemyAngleTLLEFT) {
                alertedLock = true;
            }
            if(withinAngle) {
                gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.green;
            }
            if(!withinAngle) {
                gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.red;
            }

        }

}
if (!withinRange){
        if(alteredLock) {
                alertedLock = false;
        }
}
```

There is a problem when i do this, its because once it detects the first raycast detection. It ignores the rest, and so it has this color state problem.
I found out this problem on my earlier questions, here:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90329/raycast-flashing-problem

**Edit**
alertedLock is just a bool which determines when the player has touched the restricted raycast. Due to the fact the player can only kill the enemy from a certain range and angle (withinRange && withinAngle). This is why we have alertedLock.

However, when alertedLock is true. It can only be turned off when the player isnt within the kill range of the enemy (!withinRange)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Script_v2 : MonoBehaviour {

// Player Properties
private GameObject player;
public Vector3 playerSize;
private Vector3 playerTransform;
public Vector3 playerTransformTL;
public Vector3 playerTransformTR;
public Vector3 playerTransformBL;
public Vector3 playerTransformBR;

private Vector3 newPlayerTransformTL;
private Vector3 newPlayerTransformTR;

private Vector3[] playerRaycastPoints;


// Enemy Properties
private Vector3 enemyTransformTL;
private Vector3 enemyTransformTR;
private Vector3 enemyTransformBL;
private Vector3 enemyTransformBR;

public float distance;
public Vector3 enemySize;

// Detection Alerts
public bool outOfVision;
public bool alerted;
public bool alertedLock;

public bool withinRange;
public bool withinAngle;

public bool dead;

Ray ray;
RaycastHit hit;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    playerRaycastPoints = new Vector3[4];

    distance = 3f;
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");


}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    enemyTransformTL = new Vector3 (transform.position.x - 0.5f, transform.position.y + 0.5f, transform.position.z);
    enemyTransformTR = new Vector3 (transform.position.x + 0.5f, transform.position.y + 0.5f, transform.position.z);


    enemyTransform_TL_TR ();
    Reference_Player_Transform_Points ();
    Player_Transform_Points_Detection ();

    Debug.Log (alerted + " " + alertedLock);

}

void OnDrawGizmos() {
    Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere (new Vector3(transform.position.x - 0.5f, transform.position.y + 0.5f, transform.position.z), distance);
    //Gizmos.DrawWireSphere (new Vector3(transform.position.x + 0.5f, transform.position.y + 0.5f, transform.position.z), distance);
}

public void enemyTransform_TL_TR() {

    if (alertedLock && !withinRange) {

        alertedLock = false;        

    }
    if (!alertedLock) {
        gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.blue;
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < playerRaycastPoints.Length; i++) {

        double enemyAngleTL = Mathf.Atan2(playerRaycastPoints[i].y - ( transform.position.y + 0.5f ),
                                          playerRaycastPoints[i].x - ( transform.position.x - 0.5f )) * 180f / 3.14159265f;
        //Debug.Log (enemyAngleTL);
        double enemyAngleTR = Mathf.Atan2 (playerRaycastPoints[i].y - (transform.position.y + 0.5f),
                                           playerRaycastPoints[i].x - (transform.position.x + 0.5f)) * 180f / 3.14159265f;

        Vector3 directionTL = (playerRaycastPoints[i] - enemyTransformTL).normalized;
        Ray rayTL = new Ray(enemyTransformTL, directionTL);
        RaycastHit hitTL;
        Vector3 directionTR = (playerRaycastPoints[i] - enemyTransformTR).normalized;
        Ray rayTR = new Ray (enemyTransformTR, directionTR);
        RaycastHit hitTR;

        withinRange = Physics.Raycast (rayTL, out hitTL, distance);
        withinAngle = enemyAngleTL > 90 && enemyAngleTL < 180;

        RaycastHit hitTPUP;
        RaycastHit hitTPLEFT;
        bool enemyAngleTLUP = Physics.Raycast(enemyTransformTL, Vector3.up, out hitTPUP, distance);
        bool enemyAngleTLLEFT = Physics.Raycast(enemyTransformTL, Vector3.left, out hitTPLEFT, distance);


        Debug.DrawRay(enemyTransformTL, Vector3.up * distance);
        Debug.DrawRay(enemyTransformTL, Vector3.left * distance);


        if(withinRange) {
            // Inside
            if(alertedLock) {
                gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.magenta;
            }
            if(!alertedLock) {
                if(enemyAngleTLUP || enemyAngleTLLEFT) {
                    alertedLock = true;
                }
                if(withinAngle) {
                    gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.green;
                }
                if(!withinAngle) {
                    gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.red;
                }

            }

        }




    }



}

private void Reference_Player_Transform_Points() {

    playerSize = player.transform.localScale;

    playerTransformTL = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x - (playerSize.x / 2),
                                    player.transform.position.y + playerSize.y  / 2,
                                    player.transform.position.z);
    playerTransformTR = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x + (playerSize.x / 2),
                                    player.transform.position.y + playerSize.y  / 2,
                                    player.transform.position.z);
    playerTransformBL = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x - (playerSize.x / 2),
                                    player.transform.position.y - playerSize.y  / 2,
                                    player.transform.position.z);
    playerTransformBR = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x + (playerSize.x / 2),
                                    player.transform.position.y - playerSize.y  / 2,
                                    player.transform.position.z);

    playerRaycastPoints [0] = playerTransformTL;
    playerRaycastPoints [1] = playerTransformTR;
    playerRaycastPoints [2] = playerTransformBL;
    playerRaycastPoints [3] = playerTransformBR;

    /*
        Debug.Log (playerTransformTL);
        Debug.Log (playerTransformTR);
        Debug.Log (playerTransformBL);
        Debug.Log (playerTransformBR);
    */
}

private void Player_Transform_Points_Detection() {
    float eTLpTL = Vector3.Distance (enemyTransformTL, playerTransformTL);
    float eTLpTR = Vector3.Distance (enemyTransformTL, playerTransformTR);
    float eTLpBL = Vector3.Distance (enemyTransformTL, playerTransformBL);
    float eTLpBR = Vector3.Distance (enemyTransformTL, playerTransformBR);

    float eTRpTL = Vector3.Distance (enemyTransformTR, playerTransformTL);
    float eTRpTR = Vector3.Distance (enemyTransformTR, playerTransformTR);
    float eTRpBL = Vector3.Distance (enemyTransformTR, playerTransformBL);
    float eTRpBR = Vector3.Distance (enemyTransformTR, playerTransformBR);


    float eTLMin = Mathf.Min (eTLpTL, eTLpTR, eTLpBL, eTLpBR);

    if (eTLMin == eTLpTL) {
        newPlayerTransformTL = playerTransformTL;
        // Debug.Log("eTLpTL");     
    }
    else if(eTLMin == eTLpTR) {
        newPlayerTransformTL = playerTransformTR;
        // Debug.Log("eTLpTR");
    }
    else if(eTLMin == eTLpBL) {
        newPlayerTransformTL = playerTransformBL;
        // Debug.Log("eTLpBL");
    }
    else if(eTLMin == eTLpBR) {
        newPlayerTransformTL = playerTransformBR;
        // Debug.Log("eTLpBR");
    }

    float eTRMin = Mathf.Min (eTRpTL, eTRpTR, eTRpBL, eTRpBR);

    if(eTRMin == eTRpTL) {
        newPlayerTransformTR = playerTransformTL;
        // Debug.Log("eTRpTL");
    }
    else if(eTRMin == eTRpTR) {
        newPlayerTransformTR = playerTransformTR;
        // Debug.Log("eTRpTR");
    }
    else if(eTRMin == eTRpBL) {
        newPlayerTransformTR = playerTransformBL;
        // Debug.Log("eTRpBL");
    }
    else if(eTRMin == eTRpBR) {
        newPlayerTransformTR = playerTransformBR;
        // Debug.Log("eTRpBR");
    }


}
```

}

Comment: So, when I'm understanding it correct, what you are trying to do is color the enemy to show if the player is able to hit/kill the enemy? But what is all that tranfor TL TR clutter? I have the feeling that you do it waaaay to complicated. Maybe you should explain what behavior you want to achieve in genereral.

Comment: Oh sorry about all the complicated clutter. If you look at this link i hope you will get a better understanding.
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90368/problems-with-raycasting-requirements/90460#90460

So TL just means, Top Left and TR means Top Right. Since i want to make two of these kind of detections.